# What is the product of 1+1/p^2 over all primes p?

Tags: functions

Can *Mathematica* `Sum` or `Multiply` over the set of all primes?

I can get an estimate of my question in the title with:

```
Product[1 + 1/p^2, {p, Prime[Range[1000]]}] // N
```

Can *Mathematica* return the exact value?

**Answer of Wolfgang**

I place my answer here, as it was not given in the reference quoted and there is no other entry space.

The answer in your case is yes: simply write down what you want

```
Product[1 + 1/Prime[k]^s, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[2]= Zeta[s]/Zeta[2 s] *)
```

And, specifically, for `s = 2` we have

```
Zeta[2]/Zeta[4]

(*
Out[154]= 15/\[Pi]^2
*)

% // N

(*
Out[153]= 1.51982
*)
```

Your Approximation

```
Product[1 + 1/p^2, {p, Prime[Range[1000]]}] // N

(*
Out[146]= 1.5198
*)
```

is close to the exact value.

If you wish, you can prove the formula for the product analytically.

Let

$\eta (s)=\prod _{p} \left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right)$

and consider the Riemann zeta function `Zeta[s]`, defined by

$\zeta (s)=\prod _p \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}$

Hence

$\frac{\eta (s)}{\zeta (s)}=\prod _p \left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)=\prod _p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^{2 s}}\right)=\frac{1}{\zeta (2 s)}$

Whence

$\eta (s)=\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (2 s)}$

Comment: I don't see where this question was answered before, therefore I did it here. But I would prefer to put it in an answer instead of an edit. Can somebody of the "marking crew" either explain where exactly I can find the previous question and answer, or otherwise reopen the question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Thank you Dr. Wolfgang Hintze.  Also, since every positive integer can be uniquely factored into a perfect square and a square free integer we can translate directly to a Dirichlet generating function: zeta(s) = zeta(2*s)*mu^2(s).